# Excel / VBA: How to copy data from multiple Excel files

Tags: vba, excel, loops, foreach

I would like to loop through all Excel files in a folder in order to do something with each file (all files have the same layout and only data on `Sheet1`).

So far I have the following code which gives me a list of the Excel files in a specific folder. 
What I couldn't figure out myself is how I can copy data from each file - specifically **I would need to copy the data in range A10:E50 from each file and then paste it on a page in my current file** (all below each other).

Can someone help me with this ?

**My current code:**

```
Sub FindFiles()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\mo\Desktop\Test-Import\")
    'ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The folder " & objFolder.Name & " contains the following Excel files:"

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
    Next

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance for any help, 
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below...

```
Sub FindFiles()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As File
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim srWS As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim path As String
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = "  " 'Enter your path here
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(path)
'ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The folder " & objFolder.Name & " contains the following Excel files:"

Set ws = Worksheets.Add

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    rowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If (objFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Or objFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet") Then
     Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path & objFile.Name)
     Set srWS = wb.Sheets(1)
     srWS.Range("A10:E50").Copy
     ws.Activate
     If rowCount = 1 Then
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
        ws.Cells(rowCount + 1, 1).Select
     Else
        ws.Cells(rowCount + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
        ws.Cells(rowCount + 2, 1).Select
     End If
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     wb.Close
    End If

Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - I will test and report back shortly.

Comment: Your are Welcome. If your problem is solved. please mark the question as answered. If not let me know where you are stuck at.

Comment: Thanks - I am getting an error here on the third line, Dim objFile As File. User defined type not defined.

Comment: I tested in my machine it worked fine. Try you declaration i.e., Dim objFile As Object

Comment: 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' reference should be turned on to use it as File

Comment: Defining it as object works for these lines. Next error is for non-declared variable rowCount. Should I just define this as integer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102603/discussion-between-siva-and-keewee279).

Comment: Im no longer in chat. Put you commnets if you face any issues

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I get no more error messages now but it does not import any data, just inserts a blank new sheet.

Comment: Are you sure you have excel files in the path you are assigning to 'path'? If So do you have data in Your workbooks-sheet1 in the range you mentioned in the quaetion

Comment: I recommend debug line by line see where code is not working. I m positive on the result as it worked for me.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes I have one test file with data there. Does it make a difference that this file is saved as .xlsm ?

Comment: The file from which you are trying to fetch data should be of type 'Microsoft Excel Worksheet' as i coded it that way if your files are.xlsm then you should change it to "Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet"

Comment: Awesome - that did the trick ! Thank you so much for your time and patience. :)

Comment: Happy to help anytime:)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Sub FindFiles()
Dim objFolder As String, objFile As String, r As Integer, c As Integer    'r=row, c=column
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets.Add
objFolder = "C:\Users\mo\Desktop\Test-Import\"
objFile = Dir(objFolder)
r = 10: c = 1

While objFile <> vbNullString And c < 6
    ws.Cells(r, c).Value = objFile
    r = r + 1
    If r = 51 Then
        r = 10
        c = c + 1
    End If
    objFile = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

notice this will list only number of files that fit into A10:E50 (200 files). If you have more than 200 files, macro will not include them. You can remove condition "And c < 6" if you'd like to see more, or edit "r" value to list files on more rows

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't see the solution to copy and paste the data here (ranges A10:E50) ? ;)

Comment: do you know how many files will be in that folder ? you can't fit variable number of files into static range.

Comment: Thanks - it will usually be between 1 and 5, never more than 10 files in the folder.

Comment: I updated my answer anyway, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you so much - I will test and report back shortly.